# Error metrics for the up-down time series curves

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks

I have a time series prediction! here is a graph of that. This shows the consumption of gas for a city! So, I want to define some metrics for it. However, I dont want to use the smape or mae or other metrics! Three period is important here. We have an event during the time step 11 until step 18. The period before this event, which is from 9-11 and the period after that which is 18-20. So, I should find the different metrics for these three periods. So, I want to ask that do you know any error metric for this kind of the problem? or anything like this one? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can simply calculate three separate errors, one for each period. If you don't want to do that, perhaps you could explain why. That said, [I would be careful about the MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352).